# Incorrect syntax near 'c:'

Tags: sql-server

this a sample of test SP i was created befor

when i run it "Incorrect syntax near 'c:'."

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[TextImpotedSP2]

AS

set @path = 'c:temp\TextImpoted0.txt'

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @bulk_cmd NVARCHAR(max);

SET @bulk_cmd = 
'BULK 
INSERT TextImpoted  FROM '+ @path1 + ';  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + ';'   ',ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '\n'+ ' )';


EXEC sp_executesql @bulk_cmd


--*************************
```

any one have any idea?

Answer (score 5):

There seem to be several issues. First, the variable `path` is never declared, and it's also incorrectly referred to as `path1` which needs to be changed. Second, some of the values in the `bulk_cmd` string needs to be quoted.

A corrected version that should work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TextImpotedSP2]
AS
DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(max)
SET @path = 'c:\temp\TextImpoted0.txt'

SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @bulk_cmd NVARCHAR(max);

SET @bulk_cmd = '
BULK INSERT TextImpoted 
FROM '''+ @path + ''' 
WITH 
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + ''';''' +  ',
       ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''\n'''+ ' 
    )';

--PRINT @bulk_cmd
EXEC sp_executesql @bulk_cmd
```

Also, the path string `'c:temp\TextImpoted0.txt'` should probably be `'c:\temp\TextImpoted0.txt'` as you might get unexpected results if you use a relative path.

Edit: added the solution to the follow-up question that were posted as an answer...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[TextImpoted01]
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(100) 
SELECT TOP (1) @SQL = total  FROM DealCounter

DECLARE @path NVARCHAR(max)
SET @path = 'c:\temp\TextImpoted'+ @SQL + '.txt'    

DECLARE @bulk_cmd NVARCHAR(max);    
SET @bulk_cmd = '
BULK INSERT TextImpoted 
FROM '''+ @path + ''' 
WITH 
    (
       FIELDTERMINATOR = ' + ''';''' +  ',
       ROWTERMINATOR = ' + '''\n'''+ ' 
    )';

--PRINT @bulk_cmd
EXEC sp_executesql @bulk_cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
set @path = 'c:temp\TextImpoted0.txt'
```

to

```
set @path = 'c:\temp\TextImpoted0.txt'
```

the `\` is important